# How to stop toggleclass on parent when child li gets pressed?

Tags: jquery, nested, jquery-selectors, jquery-events, siblings

This is my HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-mobile" class="menu menu-sliding">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Home</a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">IT Solutions</a>
    <span class="menu-item-toggle"><span></span></span>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">IT Services</a>
        <span class="menu-item-toggle"><span></span></span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Managed IT</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">IT Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">IT Consultancy</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Cloud Computing</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Cyber Security</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Custom Software</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="">Industries</a>
        <span class="menu-item-toggle"><span></span></span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Banking</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Capital Markets</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Enterprise Technology</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Manufacturing</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Healthcare</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Higher Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Logistics</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is my script:

```
$('ul.menu li.has-children').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('menu-expand').siblings().removeClass('menu-expand');
});
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Now the problem is whenever I am clicking the nested `li`'s i.e. `It Services / Industries` `.menu-expand` class gets removed from the parent i.e. `It Solutions` and the whole block goes in `display:none` state.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can change the key to use it properly and cover it only for first level li's like this:

```
$('ul.menu li.has-children a').on('click', function () {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('menu-expand').siblings().removeClass('menu-expand');
});
```

To work it out properly, the click event is transferred to the A tag and accordingly inner body of block.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide css with this, I want to see why its not working.

Comment: That'll be difficul,its pretty messy as i'm writing it on sass. The concept is when ".menu-expand" gets added to li child ul.submenu gets "display: block".

Comment: I think I got the issue. Its in the click event. As the whole ul li is inside that block only. I suggest use the code I created for you at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQzqxg